# How do I align two different div boxes side by side?

Tags: php, css, html

I'm new to codes so I don't know if the div boxes are exactly "different" but one is a box with just plain text that I am going to write in and the other is a form box(I already have it set up and everything) for people to sign up.

My one and only problem is I can't figure out how to put the two different div boxes side by side. This is what my page looks like right now http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/12472673/640/12472673.png
As you can see they do not align at the top very well. I used the float property which made it align incorectly

However, I want them to align perfectly from the top of the border and I want a little separation between the two in the middle. Kinda like this http://www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/12472719/640/12472719.png

Whats the best way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post your code, and whenever possible a an example posted at jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `float` property.

```
.left { float: left; }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: I recommend avoiding w3schools as a resource, a lot of their information is inaccurate. The W3C wiki does a better job of explaining the float property. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/floating

Answer (score 1):

Here try this. Give you a link to jsfiddle where you can see the live code working as you wish.

[http://jsfiddle.net/9kNDe/](http://jsfiddle.net/9kNDe/2/)

```
    <div class="big_box">
       <div class="box">do some in here</div>
       <div class="box"> do some in here</div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <style>
    .big_box {
   width: 500px;
   text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box { width: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 3px; }
.clear { clear: both }
    </style>
```

Comment: I want to keep the boxes that I have now, I don't  wanna change any of that
What I do want is to align them from the top of where the border begins. when I put "float left" it puts them side by side however it does not align them from the top. Can you help?

Comment: You can achive that by putting a margin-top on the .box css class. Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/9kNDe/4/. I'm pretty sure it was what you wanted.

Comment: We're getting close but what I want is to keep the codes I have now. I simply just wanna align the top of the borders ... Float:left; aligns them side by side but one is lower than the other(in terms of the top of the border). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.holder 
{
    clear:both;
}
.holder div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.holder .right
{
    margin-left:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#333;
    }
</style>

<div class="holder">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8kRx/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `display: inline-block` property

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.container { width:500px; }
.l { width:200px; }
.r { width:200px; float: right; }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="l">123</div>
  <div class="r">123</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `display: inline-block` property is probably what you're looking for.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHmCh/)

HTML

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box1, #box2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
    background: #00FFFF;
}

#box2 {
    background: #FF00FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and **`display: table`** to obtain boxes having the **same height** whatever their content (without relying on HTML tables for obtaining this layout, this is considered as poor coding with a reason).

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gtXv5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col box">same<br>height<br>as the<br>other<br>.box<br>whatever<br>the<br>content.<br></div>
    <div class="col gutter"><!-- empty "cell" --></div>
    <div class="col box">content lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
    display: table-cell;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.gutter {
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
}
```